# web audio analyzer on webrtc for remote stream

Tags: stream, webrtc, spectrum

We are creating a audio video application which using webRTC. The problem is we are not able to show the stream spectrum for remote but for local we are able to.

```
 // setup a analyzer
    var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.0;
    analyser.fftSize = 1024;

  // get the average for the first channel
        var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
        var average = getAverageVolume(array);
```

For local stream we are getting the frequency values inside the array, but for remote stream we are getting zero values inside the array.

If any help, will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue is described here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=241543 
Seems like we don't have any specific solution due to browser's issue.